# Asp.Net Membership System Last Activity Date in the future

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-2.0, asp.net-membership

I'm using the ASP.Net Membership system but I'm having an issue with the LastActivityDate for the users in the database. For some users, their last activity date is in the future... Definitely not supposed to happen. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the source code for the Sql Membership Provider, it uses UTC time:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(CreateInputParam("@CurrentTimeUtc", SqlDbType.DateTime, DateTime.UtcNow));
```

I would check the time difference between `DateTime.UtcNow` and your local time and see if that explains it.

Comment: Whoa that's a great catch! Thanks. I compared the current UTC time with the max last activity date and they made sense. The future date were all "off" by UTC time. So I just need to take that into account. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the date/time of the server?

Comment: The server's time is set correctly and GetDate() functions as expected.

Comment: @John - does the sql server run on the same server as the web server?  If not, did you check both?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Timezone/DST-related problem? How much in the future your users seem to be? :)